# A fun follow up problem about a convex polygon

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Find the remaining two angles of this polygon:

[image]

No trigonometry or Pytagoras' theorem allowed :D

Comment: What is allowed then ? Similarity and congruence?

Comment: @Avi Yes, congruence, angles, similarity, parallel lines, orthogonal lines.

Comment: This appears to be $S5$ from the still ongoing [SMC](http://wpr3.co.uk/MC/qsen1.pdf) math challenge, so it is too early to post (and answer). Just happened to look at a few recently flagged questions (e.g. [Show that the area of the triangle is](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1944144/show-that-the-area-of-the-triangle-is)) that linked to the respective pdf, which is how I noticed it.

Comment: @dxiv Hm, I have changed the problem, but now I am not sure whether it reveals or not the answer to the original question.

Comment: @Futurologist Sorry, I read too quickly. Your question is different, indeed, and I would say it's different enough. I can delete my previous comment if you want. In the meantime +1 for the question, and I like the answers here better than the others. Again, sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, that was really fun. You can do this, by introducing equilateral triangles at the angles of 60° namely the one at 150°-90° and the one at 60° which both split your side of length 2 in two parts. Since 180°-2*60°=60° you get there a third equilateral triangle (the green sides represent length 1 sides and the red angles are all 60°). I think you can take it from here :-) (using the sum of the angles) [image: polygon]

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following decomposition, placing in evidence 3 equilateral triangles:

[image]

Angle in D in isosceles triangle GDF is clearly $360^{\circ}-90^{\circ}-2 \times 60^{\circ}=150^{\circ}$.

Thus angles in $G$ and $F$ in the same triangle GDF are equal to $15^{\circ}.$

Thus the looked for angles in G and F are resp. $90^{\circ}+15^{\circ}=105^{\circ}$ and $2 \times 60^{\circ}+15^{\circ}=135^{\circ}.$